# Alternative option to removing row with particular value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have used the below code to remove the rows from a dataset that contain particular value of 'f_dun' column of another dataset. But it takes more than 2 hours to get the outcome. is there any option which will be less time consuming?

```
df1 = df1[~df1[['f_dun']].apply(lambda x: np.in1d(x,df3a).all(),axis=1)]\
                   .reset_index(drop=True)
```

data frame example:

df1

```
f_dun  name  zip
10      a     11
20      b     12
30      c     13
40      d     14
50      e     15
```

df2

```
f_dun   
10
20
```

ultimate data-frame that I need:

```
f_dun  name  zip
30      c     13
40      d     14
50      e     15
```

Comment: Yes, `apply` with `axis=1` is one of the most inefficient operations in pandas.  Maybe if you gave a short example with data of what you're trying to accomplish, this could be written with a vectorize solution.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question with sample data-frame.

Comment: Do you want this: `df1.loc[~df1['f_dun'].isin(df2['f_dun'])]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
df_1 = df_1[~df_1.f_fun.isin(df_2.t_fun)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.where(df1.f_dun!=df2.f_dun).dropna(how='all')
```

Comment: it gives me following error: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects